# Retrofit 2 - POST request became GET?

Tags: android, retrofit2

My `POST` request keeps sending as `GET` & got rejected by API endpoint

**MyService class**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/users/")
Call<List<User>> getUsers(@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> parameters);
```

**Request code**

```
Gson builder = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Constants.API_ENDPOINT_TEST_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(builder))
        .build();
mApiService = client.create(MyService.class);
Call<List<User>> call = mApiService.getUsers(mParameters);
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
        mResponse = response.body();
        mResponseObserver.onFinish(mResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
        mResponseObserver.onFailure();
    }
});
```

But server rejects it as it reached the server in `GET` request form !? Having checked with debugger, I saw that:

`rawResponse.request.method = GET`

Here is screenshot of watch window showing the retrofit's request object:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the request method was `GET`. But the weird part is in the `tag`, it shows a request object with `POST` method?

Am i miss something here?

**UPDATE**

I added logging interceptor & here is the log:

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://***/api/users/ http/1.1
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 56
D/OkHttp: --> END POST
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://***/api/users/ (388ms)
D/OkHttp: Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2016 11:50:23 GMT
D/OkHttp: Server: Apache
D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.34
D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
D/OkHttp: Expires: Sat, 01 Oct 2016 11:50:23 GMT
D/OkHttp: Vary: Accept-Encoding
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: SESSION_DEFAULT=***; expires=Sun, 04-Sep-2016 11:50:24 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: COOKIE[***]=***; path=/; httponly
D/OkHttp: Connection: close
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP
```

looks like the request is a `POST`. But, the server still responds with error message, saying that the request method is a `GET`

Hmm, I'll dig a little bit more into it.

Comment: remove "/" at the end of your request may fix your issue. I have same issue and when I send post method server log as **Get**, remove "/" at the end of request fix my problem.

Comment: @Amir I did & it not work.

Comment: Did you try logging? I recommend you to check `GET` request really sent. https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses

Comment: @nshmura Please see my edited part of the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the issue is the combination of 2 factors:

1. Wrong request protocol has been made (http instead of https)
2. Server responded with a weird message on wrong protocol: "GET is not supported".

ANyway, thanks @nshmura for your assistant.

Comment: So was a server issue, no?

Comment: So how did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I checked your program with logging, and confirms the `POST` request is sent.
I recommend you to check like this:

```
class TestClass {

    private void testRequest() {
        HashMap<String, String> mParameters = new HashMap<>();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);  // <-- this is the important line!

        Gson builder = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
        Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.API_ENDPOINT_TEST_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(builder))
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
        MyService mApiService = client.create(MyService.class);
        Call<List<User>> call = mApiService.getUsers(mParameters);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }


    interface MyService {
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("api/users/")
        Call<List<User>> getUsers(@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> parameters);
    }

    class User {

    }

    class Constants {
        public static final String API_ENDPOINT_TEST_URL = "http://.........";
    }
}
```

here is request log:

```
 D/OkHttp: --> POST http://......... http/1.1
 D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 0
 D/OkHttp: --> END POST
```

Here is response:

```
 D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://.............../ (167ms)
 D/OkHttp: Server: nginx
 D/OkHttp: Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2016 11:30:32 GMT
 D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 D/OkHttp: Connection: close
....
 D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP
```

Comment: I did add logging interceptor & the log show that the request looks pretty much like a `POST`. But, I really have no idea why server recognized it as `GET` & responds with an error message.

Comment: I guess `Redirect` to specific URL is happened.

Comment: I checked with a rest testing tool and the result is still ok, so I guess no redirection was made. However, I noticed that in my code, the request has been sent in normal http request instead of https. Maybe that is the root cause, I'll check this out.

Comment: Mmm.. Also I recommend you to use `charles proxy` to check the request and response https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdSrsHT_NLk

Answer (score 1):

I met a similar problem. In my case, I received in response to 301, redirect and change of method POST -> GET.

First, check your BASE_URL, it must be of the form "h ttps://www.YourSite.com/" www - very important. If everything is in place and the problem still exists, then you can change as described below:

From [okhttp wiki](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) and [based on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Do1.png), you need to change something like this:

```
...
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

final RequestBody requestBody = new FormBody.Builder().build();
httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
    @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        HttpUrl.Builder builder = request.url().newBuilder();

        HttpUrl url = builder.build();

        request = request.newBuilder()
                .url(url)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
})

httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can u try

> @POST("/api/users/")

With slash before "api"?

Also it would be helpful to double check request with [Fiddler](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid) or smth.

Answer (score 0):

That is partly correct a http client behavior. According to [the HTTP spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

> If the 307 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued.

Sometime it is not possible to change backend API. So here a workaround you can add to you interceptor to manually redirect a request with correct method.

```
fun forceRedirectMethod(chain: Interceptor.Chain, originResponse: Response): Response {

    /* TODO
        one more request is made; disable followRedirect and make it manually?
      */
    if (originResponse.priorResponse()?.code() == 302) {
        val priorResponse: Response = originResponse.priorResponse() as Response
        val redirectRequest = priorResponse.request()
        val builder = originResponse.request().newBuilder()
                .method(redirectRequest.method(), redirectRequest.body())
        val newRequest = builder.build()
        return chain.proceed(newRequest)
    } else {
        return originResponse
    }
}
```