# Request method 'POST' not supported Retrofit Android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am getting this error - `Request method 'POST' not supported` but I am not using `POST` type.

```
@GET("ads/getAdsList")
Call<ApiResponse<List<HomeAdModel>>> getAdsList();
```

I am calling it like above. But getting this error

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://abc/foodS/api/ads/getAdsList
D/OkHttp: <-- 405 http://abc/foodS/api/ads/getAdsList (1661ms)
D/OkHttp: {"timestamp":"2020-07-22T15:32:42.207+0000","status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/foodS/api/ads/getAdsList"}
```

When I check it in postman, it works. Here is the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your HTTP **client** changes `GET` to `POST` method which is not supported by the backend.

You can change the server side response return to `"307"` code **or**, switch to [`OKHTTP`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) or [`Volley`](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) library to be able to connect to the backend using custom network interceptor.

According to: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1762#issuecomment-215086267

And read: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2262#issuecomment-172933936

Comment: I am using retrofit, and there are other GET type method also, all other requests are working. This error just comes for this method.

Comment: Other users also mentioned the same situation which is caused by using `http instead of https` and also, other workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269673/retrofit-2-post-request-became-get